# Spring Websocket: How update and reflect the changes in runtime for the MessageBrokerRegistry object?

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I am working with `Spring Websocket` and with `ActiveMQ`.
For the latter exits two servers, local and remote.

When the local server is enabled (remote is offline) the following works fine:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue");                                                               
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
```

When only the remote server is enabled (local is offline) the code shown above fails with the following:

```
[main] INFO  o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Starting...
[main] INFO  o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - Connecting "system" session to 127.0.0.1:61613
...
[tcp-client-loop-nio-4] ERROR o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - TCP connection failure in session _system_:
Failed to connect: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:61613
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:61613
```

The solution is:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic","/queue").setRelayHost("192.168.1.88")
                                                  .setRelayPort(61613);                                                              
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}
```

My **question** is:

- How in runtime is possible update the `MessageBrokerRegistry` object  through the `setRelayHost` and `setRelayPort` methods and **reflect** these changes?. **But** It through the available `@Configuration` methods in the `Spring Framework` API.

**Note**: if one server is down and other remote server are available, I already have the *new* the values for the *host* and *port*.